# Why output differs in C and Java in the expression m++ + (++m)

Tags: java, c, expression

Consider:

```
int m = 2, n;

n = m++ + (++m);
```

In C output is:

```
m = 4, n = 4;
```

In Java output is:

```
m = 4, n = 5;
```

How does this happen?

Comment: which compiler do you use? the same code gives m=4 and n=6 for me (Visusal Studio 2010)

Comment: It's because you can't change the same variable twice in a statement without sequencing point. That causes undefined behavior in C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can differ because C does not allow a correct program to contain such an expression - C does not define the behaviour of such a program.  This gives C compilers wide latitude in how they interpret such expressions.

Java more tightly constrains implementations by defining the expected behaviour of expressions like this.

(The rule that this breaks in C is that an expression may not modify the value of an object more than once without an intervening sequence point).

Comment: "C does not allow a correct program to contain such an expression." Yes it does; it just doesn't specify its behaviour. Not the same thing.

Comment: @EJP: Such a program is not correct.

Comment: if such a program is not correct the compiler shouldn't compile it.

Comment: @EJP: A conforming compiler *is* allowed to reject the program in the example.  However, C compilers are not *required* to diagnose this particular error because doing so can be impossible at compile-time: consider `(*p)++ + (*q)++)`, which is OK as long as `p != q`.